# Passing an object to another class

Tags: ruby, object, reference

Using Clockwork, I periodically pull objects from my database and pass them to Sidekiq workers for processing. If I inspect the objects prior to passing them to the Sidekiq worker, I see all the fields that they have. However, inspecting the object after I pass it gives me what I assume is a reference to the object.

Clockwork function

```
every(30.seconds, 'check_modems.job'){

  modem_list = Modem.all

  modem_list.each do |modem|
    TestWorker.perform_async(modem)
    puts(modem.inspect)
  end
}
```

The output from the puts above:

```
<Object id: 1, value: "15", ipaddress: nil>
```

And my worker function that receives the object:

```
def perform(test)
  puts(test.inspect)
end
```

and the output:

```
#<Object:0x00563977f06f48>"
```

From what I have been able to find, Ruby is pass-by-value, and that value in this case is a reference, but how do I go backwards from here and get the object that I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code would be more robust when you only pass simple identifiers (e.g. numbers or strings that are easy to serialize) instead of complex objects.

Change your `clockwork` function to something like this:

```
modem_ids = Modem.pluck(:id)
modem_ids.each { |id| TestWorker.perform_async(id) }
```

And your worker to:

```
def perform(modem_id)
  modem = Modem.find_by(id: modem_id)
  if modem
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: To be more specific, the reason that you have to do that is because for something to get put into a Sidekiq queue and then processed by a Sidekiq worker, that something gets serialized and stored in Redis as a JSON string in between. See [the sidekiq docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/The-Basics)-- this is a Sidekiq thing, not a generic Ruby thing.